# Manipulating a query

Tags: wp-query, search

I'm trying to use my own search form rather than default single-field form. So I made my fields and set the values to the query by using `pre_get_posts` hook.

All things are well. Because of searching through multiple `custom fields` I'm using `meta_query` with `relation => 'OR'` as well as using multiple key/value arrays inside it.

But there is a problem I've and going to explain. This is the query that will run when submit button is clicked:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt3.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt4 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt4.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt5 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt5.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt6 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt6.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%test%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%test%')))  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'jz_ftype' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'pamphlet')
OR  (mt1.meta_key = 'jz_year' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) = '')
OR  (mt2.meta_key = 'jz_has-answer' AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'yes')
OR  (mt3.meta_key = 'jz_atc-author' AND CAST(mt3.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%%')
OR  (mt4.meta_key = 'jz_ebook-author' AND CAST(mt4.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%%')
OR  (mt5.meta_key = 'jz_pro-author' AND CAST(mt5.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%%')
OR  (mt6.meta_key = 'jz_level' AND CAST(mt6.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'basic') ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

As you can see (at the end of 7th line) the additional query I set to main query by using `$query->set()` method is being `AND`:

```
AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'jz_ftype' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'pamphlet')
```

But I need to make it `OR`:

```
OR ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'jz_ftype' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'pamphlet')
```

So how can I achieve that?

Comment: any luck so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try to add a `posts_where` filter in your `pre_get_posts` hook:

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $q ){
    if( $q->is_main_query() )
        add_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_posts_where' );

    return $q;
}
! is_admin() && add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts' );
```

where

```
function my_posts_where( $where ){

    // your custom replacements on the $where string
    // ...

    // remove the filter           
    remove_filter( current_filter() , __FUNCTION__ );

    return $where;
}
```

Comment: I used the other way to make it work however your answer theoretically is correct, so I accept it.